# www and without www Domain not working properly

Tags: dns

when i open my domain without **www** then its working properly. I have used **hostname** variable in header and footer templates without www (like

```
http://example.com
```

). When i open same link with www (like

```
http://www.example.com
```

) its showing my session has expired..

I don't know difference between these two.....

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your issue comes down to how you have your records entered in your DNS server. What it sounds like is happening is you have your host configured something like this:

```
example.com.   IN   A  192.168.1.1
```

If you want it to work for www.example.com, you could replace it with the following:

```
www.example.com.   IN   A   192.168.1.1
```

The difference all comes down to how you have your domain configured. If you're going to have multiple hosts (e.g. www, mail, ftp), then the latter case makes sense to specify all of the hosts in your domain. Otherwise, if you're just running the one host the first case would probably suffice.